# Python: Create a new variable derived from extracting a sentence from a text

Tags: python, nlp

I have a data frame which one of the variables is a fairly long paragraph containing many sentences. Sometimes the sentences are separated by a full stop sometimes by a comma. I'm trying to create a new variable by extracting only selected parts of the text using selected words. Please see below a short sample of the data frame the result I have at the moment, followed by the code I'm using. Note - the text in the first variable is pretty large.

```
PhysicalMentalDemands           Physical_driving       Physical_telephones

[driving may be necessary       [driving......]        [telephones...]
occasionally. 
as well as telephones will also 
be occasional to frequent.]
```

**Code used:**

```
searched_words = ['driving' , 'telephones']

for i in searched_words:
  Test ['Physical' +"_"+  str(i)] = Test ['PhysicalMentalDemands'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
                       if any(True for w in word_tokenize(sent) 
                                 if w.lower() in searched_words)])
```

**Issue:**

At the moment my code extract the sentences but extract using both of the words. I've seem other similar posts but none managed to solve my issue.

**Fixed**

searched_words = ['driving', 'physical']

```
for i in searched_words:
df['Physical' + '_' + i] = result['PhysicalMentalDemands'].str.lower().apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text) 
                                                           if i in word_tokenize(sent)])
```

Comment: In the 'Issue' section, you say 'extract using both of the words,' does that mean it only matches if both words are present? And are you trying to match just if either is present?

Comment: @Henry Woody , atm what is happening is that both sentences are going to both of the variables. My function is not separating driving in one variable and telephone on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want separate lists for each searched word, you might consider reorganizing your code into something like this:

```
searched_words = ['driving', 'telephones']

for searched_word in searched_words:
    Test ['Physical' +"_"+  searched_word)] = Test ['PhysicalMentalDemands'].apply(lambda text: [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
                if any(w for w in word_tokenize(sent) if w.lower() == searched_word)])
```

Note that the meat of the fix is changing `if w.lower() in searched_words` to `if w.lower() == searched_word`.

Comment: it did not worked , it returned blank. Im thinking probably around the any before ()

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira I noticed a small issue where I left a reference to `i` in there, but it sounds like that was not your problem. I just ran this on my computer and it seemed to work fine. The only thing I can think of that might cause that issue is putting `searched_words` in where `searched_word` should go.

Comment: I also implemented your answer using for i in searched words then ==i and that worked perfectly . the equal sign is succinct and I will be using for sure. tks